# How can I determine the type of object that is allowed to call specific method?

Tags: c#, class, access-modifiers

I have a `Node` class:

```
public class Node
{
    private string name;
    private Point3D location;
    private int id;
    .
    .
}
```

and a `Graph` class:

```
public class Graph
{
  ....
}
```

The id in `Node` is readonly, but I need to set its value only from `Graph` objects and not from outside the `Graph` class.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: "id in node class is readonly but I need to set its value only from Graph objects" This sounds like a bad design.  Keeping node IDs readonly is a good thing, but you lose the benefits of immutability as soon as any part of your program tries to change a node's ID.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please consider improving it.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin if the id is readonly how can something else change it once it s initialized? and actually while making an entity immutable u need to mark the fields readonly.

Comment: @DarthVader Of course you can't change a field that is readonly.  I was saying that dropping the readonly and introducing mutation is a bad idea.  However, you don't need to mark fields readonly in order to make an object immutable.  If you define a sealed class whose properties all have a public get and private set, and nothing but the constructor uses the setters, you haven't used the `readonly` keyword but you have built a class whose objects cannot be mutated by any outside code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option that may *help* (but not totally *fix* it) is to use the modifier [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on the property. This restricts the accessibility scope of the property to within the assembly it is a member of, and to any assemblies declared as friends.

Having said that, your requirement to make Id public but changeable only from a Graph object violates OO concepts. A way to work round this is to restrict creation of Node objects to within the Graph class, or from a factory method only available to the Graph class. If you do this and have the Id property exposed as public with only a getter, and assign it a value in the constructor then you will achieve 90% of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

you can make the `Node` class a private nested class of `Graph` class so only `Graph` class can access and modify it, you can have methods to access your graph nodes from public methods within `Graph` class

Comment: I think making `Node` a private nested class is not very useful. You should be able to use it from outside directly.

Comment: @svick you can use it via Graph class public methods. but well it s just an idea. i dont know what u are thinking.

Comment: This is the approach used internally by for instance XmlWriter's abstract factory implementation. It's surely a valid approach, but requires an abstract base class that's publicly accessible (assuming it should be made public at all).

Answer (score 0):

```
public NameSpace{
    public class Node{
      public int Id { get; internal set; }
      // rest of the code...
    }

    public class Graph{
      // Node Id can be set here...
    }
}
```

Does this work?